# How to apply SeekBar value to a calculation in a method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, seekbar

I want to be able to take the seekbar value selected by user (# of years) and add it to the calculatePayments(View clickedButton) method. This seekbar value will then be divided by 1200 as shown in the code below, but I am confused how to link the seekbar value with the math calculation. Any help? Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText loanAmount, interestRate, loanYears;
    private TextView monthlyPaymentsResult, totalPaymentsResult;
    private static SeekBar seek_bar;
    private static TextView textview_seek;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seekbarr();
        loanAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loanAmtET);
        interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.intRateET);
        //loanYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.);
        monthlyPaymentsResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthlyResultTV);
        totalPaymentsResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalResultTV);
    }

    public void seekbarr() {
        seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        textview_seek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarTV);
        textview_seek.setText(seek_bar.getProgress() + "Years");

        seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int years_number = 5;

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                textview_seek.setText(years_number + " Years");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                years_number = progress;
                textview_seek.setText(years_number + " Years");
            }
        });
    }

    public void calculatePayments(View clickedButton) {
        double loan = Integer.parseInt(loanAmount.getText().toString());
        double interest = (Integer.parseInt(interestRate.getText().toString()));

        double years = Integer.parseInt(textview_seek.getText().toString());

        double r = years / 1200;
        double r1 = Math.pow(r + 1, years);

        double monthlyPayment = (double) ((r + (r / (r1 - 1))) * loan);
        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * years;

        monthlyPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment));
        totalPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalPayment));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SeekBar class is a subclass of ProgressBar, which contains a getProgress() method.

Calling `seek_bar.getProgress()` will return the value you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried calling seek_bar.getProgress() as you suggested, but when I run it and press the button to calculate it remains blank still and doesn't show any results. Can you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: It's at the bottom of my code. It won't let me paste here again

Comment: your method for calculation is fine. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When I run the program and click on the calculate button to get results, it doesn't show any results. Where should I call the seek_bar.getProgress() like you said I should?

Comment: although you are providing seek bar value in your method via textview so if that is the problem use that code for `double years variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your method

```
public void calculatePayments(int year) {

    double loan = Integer.parseInt(loanAmount.getText().toString());
    double interest = (Integer.parseInt(interestRate.getText().toString()));

    int years = year;

    double r = years / 1200;
    double r1 = Math.pow(r + 1, years);

    double monthlyPayment = (double) ((r + (r / (r1 - 1))) * loan);
    double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * years;

    monthlyPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment));
    totalPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalPayment));
}
```

Now call this method.

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        calculatePayments(profress);
        textview_seek.setText(years_number + " Years");

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I want to keep the button on my program so editing the method won't help me much...I need to figure out how to make the calculation work while keeping the calculatePayments button. If you have any clues, I'd appreciate it!